# Go mockgen, mocked function not called

Tags: go

I am using Go 1.19 on a windows machine with 8 cores, operating system is Windows 10 Pro.
I used the mockgen tool to generate the mock. When I debug my test I see the mocked method is recorded when I execute the EXPECT() function.
The mocked function is called, but the test fails with 'missing call' on the mocked function.
I cannot see what I am doing wrong, can anyone please point it out ?

```
Directory Structure :
cmd
 configure.go
 configure_test.go
mocks
  mock_validator.go
validator
  validator.go
user
  user.go 
go.mod
main.go
```

```
* Contents of main.go
package main
import (
                "localdev/mockexample/cmd"
)
func main() {
                cmd.Configure()
}
* Contents of configure.go
package cmd
import (
                "fmt"
                "localdev/mockexample/user"
                "os"
                "localdev/mockexample/validator"
)
var (
                name, password string
)
func Configure() {
                name := os.Args[1]
                password := os.Args[2]
                user, err := validate(validator.NewValidator(name, password))
                if err != nil {
                                fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
                                return
                }
                fmt.Printf("Credentials are valid. Welcome: %s %s\n", user.FirstName, user.LastName)
}
func validate(validator validator.Validator) (*user.Data, error) {
                user, err := validator.ValidateUser()
                if err != nil {
                                return nil, fmt.Errorf("some thing went wrong. %v", err)
                }
                return user, nil
}
* Contents of validator.go
package validator
import (
                "fmt"
                "localdev/mockexample/user"
)
//go:generate mockgen -destination=../mocks/mock_validator.go -package=mocks localdev/mockexample/validator Validator
type Validator interface {
                ValidateUser() (*user.Data, error)
}
type ValidationRequest struct {
                Command  string
                Name     string
                Password string
}
func (vr ValidationRequest) ValidateUser() (*user.Data, error) {
                if vr.Name == "bob" && vr.Password == "1234" {
                                return &user.Data{UserID: "123", UserName: "bsmith", FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Smith"}, nil
                }
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid credentials")
}
func NewValidator(name string, password string) Validator {
                return &ValidationRequest{Name: name, Password: password}
}
* Contents of user.go
package user
type Data struct {
                UserID    string `json:"user_id"`
                UserName  string `json:"user_name"`
                FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
                LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
}
* Contents of configure_test.go
package cmd
import (
                "localdev/mockexample/mocks"
                "localdev/mockexample/user"
                "os"
                "testing"
 
                "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
)
func TestConfigure(t *testing.T) {
                t.Run("ConfigureWithMock", func(t *testing.T) {
                                os.Args[1] = "bob"
                                os.Args[2] = "1234"
 
                                ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
                                mockValidator := mocks.NewMockValidator(ctrl)
                                //mockValidator.EXPECT().ValidateUser().AnyTimes() // zero more calls, so this will also pass.
                                userData := user.Data{UserID: "testId"}
                                mockValidator.EXPECT().ValidateUser().Return(&userData, nil).Times(1) //(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()) //(&userData, nil)
                                Configure()
                })
}
Contents of generated mock
// Code generated by MockGen. DO NOT EDIT.
// Source: localdev/mockexample/validator (interfaces: Validator)
// Package mocks is a generated GoMock package.
package mocks
import (
                user "localdev/mockexample/user"
                reflect "reflect"
                gomock "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
)
// MockValidator is a mock of Validator interface.
type MockValidator struct {
                ctrl     *gomock.Controller
                recorder *MockValidatorMockRecorder
}
// MockValidatorMockRecorder is the mock recorder for MockValidator.
type MockValidatorMockRecorder struct {
                mock *MockValidator
}
// NewMockValidator creates a new mock instance.
func NewMockValidator(ctrl *gomock.Controller) *MockValidator {
                mock := &MockValidator{ctrl: ctrl}
                mock.recorder = &MockValidatorMockRecorder{mock}
                return mock
}
// EXPECT returns an object that allows the caller to indicate expected use.
func (m *MockValidator) EXPECT() *MockValidatorMockRecorder {
                return m.recorder
}
// ValidateUser mocks base method.
func (m *MockValidator) ValidateUser() (*user.Data, error) {
                m.ctrl.T.Helper()
                ret := m.ctrl.Call(m, "ValidateUser")
                ret0, _ := ret[0].(*user.Data)
                ret1, _ := ret[1].(error)
                return ret0, ret1
}
// ValidateUser indicates an expected call of ValidateUser.
func (mr *MockValidatorMockRecorder) ValidateUser() *gomock.Call {
                mr.mock.ctrl.T.Helper()
                return mr.mock.ctrl.RecordCallWithMethodType(mr.mock, "ValidateUser", reflect.TypeOf((*MockValidator)(nil).ValidateUser))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that the function `Configure` never uses the mock structure, so you get a `missing call(s) to *mocks.MockValidator.ValidateUser()` error.

In the file `configure_test.go`, `mockValidator` is simply not used at all. There must be some kind of injection of that mock in order to be called by the `Configure` function.

You could make the following changes to fix the test, as an example of what I'm referring to injection. Not saying this is the best approach but I'm trying to make the fewer possible changes to your code.

`configure_test.go`:

```golang
func TestConfigure(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("ConfigureWithMock", func(t *testing.T) {
        os.Args[1] = "bob"
        os.Args[2] = "1234"

        ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
        mockValidator := mocks.NewMockValidator(ctrl)
        //mockValidator.EXPECT().ValidateUser().AnyTimes() // zero more calls, so this will also pass.
        userData := user.Data{UserID: "testId"}
        mockValidator.
            EXPECT().
            ValidateUser("bob", "1234").
            Return(&userData, nil).
            Times(1) //(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()) //(&userData, nil)
        Configure(mockValidator)
    })
}
```

`configure.go`

```golang
func Configure(v validator.Validator) {
    name := os.Args[1]
    password := os.Args[2]
    user, err := v.ValidateUser(name, password)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("some thing went wrong. %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Credentials are valid. Welcome: %s %s\n", user.FirstName, user.LastName)
}
```

`validator.go`

```golang
type Validator interface {
    ValidateUser(name, password string) (*user.Data, error)
}
type ValidationRequest struct {
    Command string
    // Name     string
    // Password string
}

func (vr ValidationRequest) ValidateUser(name, password string) (*user.Data, error) {
    if name == "bob" && password == "1234" {
        return &user.Data{UserID: "123", UserName: "bsmith", FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Smith"}, nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid credentials")
}

func NewValidator() Validator {
    return &ValidationRequest{}
}
```

Take into account that you need to generate the mock again. Hope this helps you to understand mock testing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, it works. I am new to Go and wonder if this is the best approach.

Comment: In general, I use mocks to test operations that depend on external services. Databases, API clients, other services (if you have microservices), etc. So you don't have to run those services to test your functionality. I would not use mocks in your particular case but it depends on the struct that implements the `Validator` interface.